# How do i find exact status of my microphone mute or unmute or the volume level of mic using command line?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, command-line, pulseaudio, alsa

This is very odd, i have one default microphone and i have another second microphone. When i use this command it always shows not muted but the microphone volume is 0%. How or what is a way i can find those value accurately.

```
$ pactl list | sed -n '/^Source/,/^$/p' | grep Mute
    Mute: no
    Mute: no
    Mute: no
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the [Pulseaudio Command Line Interface](http://pulseaudio.org/wiki/CLI) we will obtain a lot of information on available sources

```
pacmd list-sources
```

will display a rather lengthy list. The current active input is marked with an asterisk. We could combine this with `grep` but will then lose information for which source the outputs are valid

```
pacmd list-sources | grep volume
```

To set an output to a defined value we need to know it's index which is also given by `list-sources` to issue

```
pacmd set-source-volume <index> <value> # value: 0 = mute 65536 = 100%
```

We may also need to unmute the sink source with

```
pacmd set-source-mute <index> 0
```

Answer (score 4):

You access this information with `amixer`.
To list all sound controls you can issue the command

```
$ amixer controls
...
numid=18,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Source'
numid=19,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
numid=20,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'
...
```

and then read the values of the controls with

```
$$ amixer cget numid=20
numid=20,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=15,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
```

Check out the man pages of `amixer`. Interesting is also `alsamixer`, which gives you a more intuitive command line interface.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do this via `pactl` and this is what I came up with:

```
# Get active audio source index
CURRENT_SOURCE=$(pactl info | grep "Default Source" | cut -f3 -d" ")

# List lines in pactl after the source name match and pick mute status
pactl list sources | grep -A 10 $CURRENT_SOURCE | grep "Mute: yes"
```

Comment: Great script. This works better than other methods, because I have 2 different microphones (internal and external), and this script works despite the current enabled input card.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution to toggle/untoggle the microphone mute with one line

I believe this helps

I created a mictoggle online script

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/mictoggle

pactl list sources | grep -qi 'Mute: yes' && pactl set-source-mute 1 false || pactl set-source-mute 1 true
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked.

Comment: I agree with guntbert that this is not what the OP asked and yet I up voted because it is exactly what I was looking for.